# Chrome off-screen tab capture API, and extension whitelisting

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'd like to use the [Chrome off-screen tab capture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture#method-captureOffscreenTab) in my extension.  So, I worked up a manifest with the `tabCapture` permission, and some code to try it out:

```
chrome.tabCapture.captureOffscreenTab('http://example.com', {
  audio: true,
  video: true
}, function () {
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Unfortunately, I get this error on my console:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabCapture.captureOffscreenTab: Extension is not whitelisted for use of the unstable, in-development chrome.tabCapture.captureOffscreenTab API.

How can I whitelist my extension?

I found a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=537732) where there was an ask to use `_api_features.json` rather than hard-coded extension IDs, but I couldn't find that file.

Comment: You can only whitelist it locally using `--whitelisted-extension-id=yourextensionid` command line switch.

Comment: @wOxxOm Good enough for me, I'm just experimenting anyway.  Thanks a ton!  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm BOOOOMSSHHaakalakalshakalaka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@wOxxOm answered this question!

Snag the ID of the extension on `chrome://extensions`.  Run Chrome like so:

```
chrome.exe --whitelisted-extension-id=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

It works great!